# Liquid behaviour under high pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If we put a liquid assume water in a cylinder (non isolated) and compress it up to 1000MPa.

How can i calculate the temperature change?

Comment: Do you mean non-insulated?

Comment: If you knew the water compressed by some small factor, like 0.001%, then you know force and distance which is energy.  Also assume the heat capacity of Joules per degree C has not changed and it can be calculated.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry for the error. yes i mean non-insulated. Assume a piston in a cylinder pressurizing the liquid to 10000  bar. Can you direct me to equations which i can use to find out the temperature increase?

Comment: If it’s non/insulated, then the final temperature change is zero.

Comment: It all depends on how fast you are pressurizing the water. If you pressurize it slowly enough and it's not thermally insulated from the rest of the world, then the temperature will remain fairly constant (i.e., you will be compressing the water isothermally). If, on the other hand, you compress the water very rapidly so there isn't much time for it to exchange heat with the rest of the world, you then have an adiabatic compression in which some temperature rise can be expected. Don't think that water compresses by a lot by P=10 kbars, though, so I wouldn't expect very much temperature rise.